# having difficulty with reset reset password to update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

i have been working on the reset password but i am receiving this error

xhr.js:251     POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/forgot-password 404 (Not Found)

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

i have tried to fix it different ways but could can someone help me with it

router

```
// FORGOT PASSWORD || METHOD POST
router.post("/forgot-password", forgotPasswordConttroller);
```

code for the forgot password page
import { React, useState } from 'react'
import Layout from '../../components/layout/Layout'
import axios from 'axios'
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const ForgotPassword = () => {

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState("")
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("")



const navigate = useNavigate()

// handle function

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/api/v1/auth/forgot-password', {
            email,
            newPassword,
            answer,
        }
        );
        if (res && res.data.success) {
            toast.success(res.data.message)

            navigate('/login');

        } else {
            toast.error(res.data.message)
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        toast.error('something went wrong')

    }
}
return (
    <Layout title='Forgot-Password'>
        <div className="signup">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h4>Reset Password</h4>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }}
                        className="form-control"
                        id="exampleInputEmail1"
                        placeholder='Email'
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="text"
                        value={answer}
                        onChange={(e) => { setAnswer(e.target.value) }}
                        className="form-control"
                        id="exampleInputEmail1"
                        placeholder='Name Of Your First Pet'
                        required

                    />
                </div>

                <div className="mb-3">
                    <input type="password"
                        value={newPassword}
                        onChange={(e) => { setNewPassword(e.target.value) }}
                        className="form-control"
                        id="exampleInputPassword1"
                        placeholder='Password'
                        required

                    />
                </div>

                <button type="submit"
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                >
                    Reset Password
                </button>


            </form>


        </div>

    </Layout>
)
```

}

export default ForgotPassword```

code for controller for forgot password

```
// forgotPasswordConttroller

export const forgotPasswordConttroller = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { newPassword, email, answer } = req.body;
    if (!email) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: "email is required" });
    }
    if (!answer) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: "answer is required" });
    }
    if (!newPassword) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: "new password is required" });
    }

    // checking validation

    const user = await userModel.findOne({ email, answer });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        sucess: false,
        message: "Wrong Email Or Answer",
      });
    }
    const hash = await hashPassword(newPassword);
    await userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, { password: hash });
    res.status(200).send({
      success: true,
      message: "password Reset successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      sucess: false,
      message: "something went very wrong",
      error,
    });
  }
};
```

server.js file code

```
 import express from "express";
    import colors from "colors";
    import dotenv from "dotenv";
    import morgan from "morgan";
    import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
    import authRoute from "./routes/authRoute.js";
    import cors from "cors";
    // configring the .env
    dotenv.config();
    
    // config database
    connectDB();
    
    // rest objects to create rest apis
    const app = express();
    
    // config morgan middleware
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(morgan("dev"));
    
    //routes
    app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoute);
    
    //  creating rest apis
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.send("<h1>welcome to Ecommerce app </h1>");
    });
    
    // creating port or host
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    
    // run the app or listen the app
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(
        `server running in ${process.env.DEV_MODE} mode on port ${PORT}`.bgCyan
          .white
      );
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure the path begins with `"/api/v1/auth"`?

Comment: actually i am not sure. i am beginner and following a youtube video, its same as the video. this is the same path used for signing up as well, and it works for that. if you don't mind can you tell how can i check it and confirm it @Aleksandar

Comment: There where you are mounting this *router*, what's the path on the `app.use(...` call? The code is most likely in the file where you call `app.listen()`

Comment: Additionally you can post the full code of the `forgotPasswordConttroller`. EDIT: I noticed you have a typo (con**tt**roller), if the typo is only in this router file then you're passing `undefined` to the `router.post("/forgot-password")`, if not, post more of your code.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Aleksandar. i have attached the code for server file where the path was given. please have a look if it helps to understand the issue. thanks

Comment: i have update the forgot password code as well.

Comment: Since your error status code is `404`, it means your `if (!user)` condition is truthy, meaning: `user` equals to `null` which triggers your `message: "Wrong Email Or Answer"`. You can confirm by including `console.log('user:', user)` before the condition.